# How to fwrite NA values as empty, not empty quotes

Tags: r, csv, data.table, na

When I `fwrite` to csv, I am getting empty quotes for NA values

I would prefer nothing at all

Here is the csv

```
# csv_in
1,2,,3
4,5,Dave,6
```

```
x = fread(csv_in)
fwrite(x, path.csv)

# Output
# 1,2,"",3
# 4,5,Dave,6

# Desired output
# 1,2,,3
# 4,5,Dave,6
```

I cannot find any way of setting `na =` to get this output

**EDIT**

The dput is a clue to the issue

```
# csv_in
1,2,,3
4,5,Dave,6

structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 4L), V2 = c(2L, 5L), V3 = c("", "Dave"
), V4 = c(3L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000111ef0>)

# csv_in_alternative
1,2,,3
4,5,,6

structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 4L), V2 = c(2L, 5L), V3 = c(NA, NA), 
    V4 = c(3L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000111ef0>)
```

Still don't know how to control this behaviour however

Comment: Please make a reproducible example, i.e. `dput(x)` and paste it in.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output: when I have an `NA`, I get an empty space, no quotes; when I have literal empty string `""`, I get the double quotes.

Comment: I added a reproducible example. Interestingly, it only happens when there is another row with a character value. A numerical value in place of "Dave" does not produce empty quotes

Comment: Your example reinforces my comment about empty strings, where I do not see `NA` written with quotes (just `""`). If you are confident that the rest of your data is "safe", then you can use `fwrite(..., quote=FALSE)` to disable all quoting, even with `NA` and `""`. (Note that data with quote marks or commas will break when read-in.)

Comment: I've added the dput - I can see that that blanks are treated differently depending on whether there is other data present or not.

Comment: @r2evans Unfortunately, I cannot be confident about the rest of the data

Comment: What we probably need is the `dput()` of what you're putting *into* `fwrite()`. When I do `fwrite(data.table(x = c(1, 2, NA, 4), y = c(4, 5, NA, 7)))` and `fwrite(data.table(x = c(1, 2, NA, 4), y = c(4, 5, "Dave", 7)))`, in both cases I seem to get the exact behavior you're hoping for. Notably, that's the transpose of your given data... any chance you're running it through `t()` first or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

add quote=F

```r
fwrite(x, path.csv, quote=F)
```